# Asynchronous enqueueWriteBuffer not executed on Intel OpenCL for iGPU

Tags: asynchronous, opencl, intel, gpgpu

I encountered a problem with asynchronous data transfer on the iGPU of a Intel Core i7-7600U.

The core part of the code from a trivial example:

```
std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
auto platform = platforms.front();
std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, &devices);
auto device = devices.front();

cl::Context context(device);
char buf[16];
cl::Buffer memBuf(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(buf));

cl::CommandQueue queue(context, device);
cl::Event ev;
queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(memBuf, CL_FALSE, 0, sizeof(buf), buf, NULL, &ev);
int status;
do{
    ev.getInfo(CL_EVENT_COMMAND_EXECUTION_STATUS, &status);
}while(status != 0);
std::cout << "DONE" << std::endl;
```

What it should do is busy waiting on the data transfer. This could be included in a scheduler (and is in starPU)

However it doesn't pass the loop. When I use the CPU instead (`CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU`) it works. When I use `ev.wait()` or `queue.finish()` it works.

Is this an Intel bug? Is there anything in the OpenCL standard, that allows the implementation to delay the scheduling till it is actually waited for?

For reference: Using Linux Mint, Kernel `4.13.0-32-generic #35~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP`.
OpenCL runtime from https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers (intel-opencl-r5.0 (SRB5.0) Linux driver package) and installed via:

```
sudo alien --to-deb *.rpm
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo ln -s /opt/intel/opencl/include/CL /usr/local/include/CL
sudo apt-get install ocl-icd-libopencl1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCL commands enqueued by clEnqueueXXX do not start execution, until you call `clFlush` or `clFinish` functions.

- `clFlush` basically moves all commands from `CL_QUEUED` state to `CL_SUBMITTED` state (see [clGetEventInfo](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clGetEventInfo.html) documentation for a list of all states).
- `clFinish` does the same as `clFlush`, but also blocks until all commands in a queue finish execution.

In your example, you should add `clFlush` call before the loop to make it work.

Edit: some OpenCL implementations can do an implicit clFlush after enqueue, so a command can start right after clEnqueueXXX call. This is not portable, and for general case, you should still use `clFlush` or `clFinish`.

Comment: Since CL_QUEUED is a valid return value, you'd think the clFlush would not be needed. OP: what is status equal to? That should give a clue.

Comment: Yes status is `CL_QUEUED`. Interesting as a) I did not know that I need to flush OCL queues and b) that a library/runtime created in 2010 has obviously a bug. Also it is strange, that you don't need a flush for host devices.

Comment: @Dithermaster CL_QUEUED means it's been put onto the command queue's "TODO list". CL_SUBMITTED means it has been actually submitted to the device for execution. An implementation may choose to submit commands to device immediately, but it may also choose to submit in batches (on clFlush), for better performance. GPUs usually do the latter.

Comment: To elaborate on "submitted": I think it is good to think of `CL_QUEUED` = queued in the host side list, `CL_SUBMITTED` = queued in the device side list. Reason is, that it might still be in the device driver and not actually in the device (which normally does not matter). But yeah basic workflow is: Prepare by queuing on the host, submit to device, wait for execution and synchronize afterwards (completed). All of that is indicated by one state

Comment: @Andrew Could you update the answer by mentioning that execution **can** start before clFlush? Because that is what is happening on CPUs and I speculate on CUDA devices (the cuda calls are similar but don't have a flush, so if the OCL driver maps them directly it would flush each enqueued command immediately)